# Problem with datagridview and sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

this is my problem. I have a datagridview where by selecting the boxes I delete the corresponding row and update the database.
If I dataEmployed.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0 then I don't delete the last line left, if I putdataEmployed.CurrentCell.RowIndex >= 0 it gives me an exception error.
Where am I wrong?

```
   private void DeleterowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataEmployed.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Il database è vuoto", "Attenzione", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            string dbConnection = "Data Source=" + path + ";Version=3";
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM Staff WHERE Id = @rowID", conn);
                conn.Open();
                if (dataEmployed.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)
                {
                    int selectIndex = dataEmployed.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                    int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(dataEmployed[0, selectIndex].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowID", DbType.Int32).Value = rowID;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataEmployed.Rows.RemoveAt(selectIndex);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot delete new unsaved row.' at dataEmployed.Rows.RemoveAt(selectIndex);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error sounds like… *”Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.”*, … this error is coming from the `DataGridView.` It is complaining about the code specifically trying to “delete/remove” the grids “new” row. This is easily fixable and is demonstrated below.

The current code is somewhat confusing in a sense that the `if` statement…

```
if (dataEmployed.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0) { …
```

… is checking if the grids `CurrentCell.RowIndex` is greater than zero (0). Then, when the code gets to actually deleting the row, the code uses a “different” row index than the one checked in the previous `if` statement.

```
int selectIndex = dataEmployed.SelectedRows[0].Index;
dataEmployed.Rows.RemoveAt(selectIndex)
```

This code uses the `SelectedRows[0].Index` to delete the row. The problem here is that the grids `CurrentCell.RowIndex` may not necessarily be the same row index as the currently “Selected” row. So, the code is checking Y and using X.

Therefore, when the code tries to remove the row from a “different” index `selectIndex`, it should not be a surprise if the two indexes are different. The code needs the `if` statement to check the grids `SelectedRows[0].Index.`

Specifically, we want to check if the “selected” row index IS the “new” row index. And… fortunately, the grid has a row property specifically for this called `IsNewRow` and will return true if the row IS the “new” row. …

```
if (!dataEmployed.Rows[selectIndex].IsNewRow) { …
```

I am confident that these small changes should eliminate the error you are getting.

```
private void DeleterowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (dataEmployed.SelectedRows.Count == 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("No rows are selected", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
  }
  int selectIndex = dataEmployed.SelectedRows[0].Index;
  if (!dataEmployed.Rows[selectIndex].IsNewRow) {
    string dbConnection = "Data Source=" + path + ";Version=3";
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)) {
      SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM Staff WHERE Id = @rowID", conn);
      conn.Open();
      int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(dataEmployed[0, selectIndex].Value);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowID", DbType.Int32).Value = rowID;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      dataEmployed.Rows.RemoveAt(selectIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, it is unknown how the code is initially filling the grid and/or if it uses a data source. I highly recommend you use a `BindingSource` or `BindingList` as a data source to the grid. It will make things easier. Using code, in most cases, it is rare/frowned upon to remove rows “directly” from the grid. In most cases you would want to remove the row from the grids data source and let the grid automatically get updated. This is just a suggestion and is another story.

I hope this makes sense. Good Luck.